# Cannot start Hadoop Namenode- syntax error

Tags: hadoop

After I install Hadoop-2.8.0 start by running command "start-all.cmd", Datanode, Nodemanager and Resourcemanager start well. However, namenode cannot start with the below error:

```
ERROR common.Util: Syntax error in URI C:\Hadoop-2.8.0\data\namenode. Please check hdfs configuration.
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Hadoop-2.8.0\data\namenode
```

I checked hdfs-site.xml, I configured it as below and try to search a lot but I cannot fix the error.

```
<configuration>
   <property>
     <name>dfs.replication</name>
     <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>C:\Hadoop-2.8.0\data\namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>C:\Hadoop-2.8.0\data\datanode</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Can you help me to figure out where is the fault?

Comment: can you try the following path for namenode dir: `C:/Hadoop-2.8.0/data/namenode`

Comment: I tried with that but it shows the error as below:
`ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode. 
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are not accessible or do not exist.`

Comment: then it might be a permission issue. Try to give write permission to the directory

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try your advice! Appreciate your opinion!